# Cloud functions - Overwrite data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I wrote function that write to the Database (Real time database).
My problem is that for some reason every time i write to a spasific node, it adds the whole data and then delete them all beside only one.

[image]

This is the node. For some reason the data keeps being delete and leaves only one data under ID.

**THIS IS THE CODE**

```
 function sendVideosToUserFeed(videosList,userUID){
  let promises = []
  videosList.forEach(video =>{
  console.log("Video function",video);
  promises.push(admin.database().ref("userFeed").child(userUID).set(video));
})

 return Promise.all(promises).then(snapshot =>{
 console.log("Sent succssesful ","worked");
 return true
 }).catch(error =>{
 console.log("Error ",error);
})
```

}

In this code I'm running on a loop that has the data and set it to a spasific node.
Each data I want it to be saved under user UID.
So I'm setting the reference to each data and then use Promis.all to run all.
But like i said it keeps adding them all and then delete all of them beside one.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**THE SOLUTION**

```
function sendVideosToUserFeed(videosList,userUID){
let promises = []
 videosList.forEach(video =>{
  promises.push(admin.database().ref("userFeed").child(userUID).child(video.videoID).set(video));
  })

 return Promise.all(promises).then(snapshot =>{
   console.log("Sent succssesful ","worked");
   return true
 }).catch(error =>{
   console.log("Error ",error);
 })
}
```

I'm saving my data like that : Head node -> user UID -> video ID -> DATA

Comment: That doesn't look like the whole code ... I don't see a usage of the function sendVideosToUserFeed().   What database technology are you using?

Comment: Your code is, in fact, overwriting the same `userUID` node every time.  What do you expect this code to do differently?  Could you should an example of what you want the database to look like?

Comment: You are right, It always update the same node. I have editted my question with the solution

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you should answer your question using the answer box at the bottom - don't edit the answer into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE SOLUTION**

```
function sendVideosToUserFeed(videosList,userUID){
let promises = []
 videosList.forEach(video =>{
  promises.push(admin.database().ref("userFeed").child(userUID).child(video.videoID).set(video));
  })

 return Promise.all(promises).then(snapshot =>{
   console.log("Sent succssesful ","worked");
   return true
 }).catch(error =>{
   console.log("Error ",error);
 })
}
```